# Cardinality of a set that contains a transitive relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to compute the cardinality of the following set:
$$A= \{ R\subset \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} : R \text { is  a transitive relation}\}$$

I understand that the cardinality is bounded above by $|P(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})| = 2^{\aleph_0}= \aleph$, but how to find a lower bound?

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}$ is better denoted $\mathfrak{c}$ instead of plain $\aleph$ which is no longer a common notation for the continuum.

Comment: There are probably several other good candidates for these sort of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also $2^{\aleph_0}$. For each $S\subseteq \Bbb N$, let $R_0$ be the relation $a\mathrel{R_0}b\iff a\in S\land b=a+1$. Then let $R$ be the transitive closure of $R_0$ and observe $a \mathrel R a+1\iff a\in S$.

Comment: And if we were given that $R$ is not transitive; i.e $B:= \{ R \subset \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} : \text{ R is not transitive}\}$; then because $B\cup A = P(\mathbb{N}\cup \mathbb{N})$, I believe we can find a one-to-one bijection of $B$ to $A$, not sure how to write it down. can you help me with this?

Comment: can you please answer my second question in the above comment? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call $\Delta_S$ the relation $a\ \Delta_S\ b\iff a=b\land a\in S\land b\in S$. The map \begin{align}\Delta_\bullet:\mathcal P(\Bbb N)&\to A\\ S&\mapsto \Delta_S\end{align}

is injective: in fact, the map $\operatorname{dom}:A\to \mathcal P(N)$ assigning to a relation its domain satisfies $\operatorname{dom}(\Delta_S)=S$.

Answer (score 0):

A well ordering is transitive. The natural ordering is a well order. Pick any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and take the natural ordering restricted to this set. The resulting is a transitive relation on $\mathbb{N}$. There are continuumly many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. This provides a lower bound.